# How to implement CSS scroll-snap to work with Safari?

Tags: css, scroll

I have tried to implement a full screen card stacking scroll effect using CSS `position: sticky` and `scroll-snap`. It works perfectly on Chrome, but on latest Safari browsers (both on mobile and desktop) it has problems. When I try to scroll backward it doesn't snap and it is very laggy. I have checked the browser compatibility and in theory it should work. Is it a Safari problem or I missed something?

Here is a codepen where to problem is present: https://codepen.io/vinceumo/pen/aboYLBW